# How to modify this piece of code to create a KeyListener that listens to keyboard input even when it's not typed into a text field?

Tags: java

I want to write a program that will read the user's keyboard inputs regardless of what the user is clicking on. I've only gotten it working by having the user input text into a text field, even though my KeyListener is testing for the KeyPressed event and not the KeyTyped one.

This is for a simulation of Conway's Game of Life. The intent is to read the user's key inputs to see if they input a specific key, which will pause the simulation. I tried not including the TextField and adding the KeyListener to the JFrame directly but it wouldn't read my inputs. I tried setting the TextField's visibility to false, which also wouldn't read my inputs.

Here's what I have right now:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class Listener
{
    private JFrame j;
    private KeyInput k;

    public Listener()
    {
        j = new JFrame();
        Container c = j.getContentPane();
        k = new KeyInput();
        JTextField t = new JTextField();
        t.addKeyListener(k);
        c.add(t);
        j.setFocusable(true);
        j.pack();
        j.setVisible(true);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }

    public char getKeyPressed()
    {
        return k.getKeyPressed();
    }

    public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter
    {
        private char ch = 0;

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev)
        {
            ch = ev.getKeyChar();
        }

        public char getKeyPressed()
        {
            return ch;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to modify this code somehow so that the program can read user input without the need for a text field.

Answer (score 0):

If i didn't get you wrong, this would be helpful :)

```
import javax.swing.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;
public class Test {

    public Test () {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        // this line is optionnel, i just wrote it to see the JFrame when testing
        jFrame.setSize(300, 180);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        KeyInput keyInput = new KeyInput() ;
        jFrame.addKeyListener (new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // stores the pressed key value in the currentCaracter field of keyInput
                keyInput.setCurrentCaracter (e.getKeyChar()) ;
                // prints out the value stored, for testing
                System.out.println(keyInput.getCurrentCaracter());
            }
        }) ;

    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new Test();
    }

}

class KeyInput{
    public KeyInput() {
    }
    public void setCurrentCaracter (char currentCaracter)
    {
        this.currentCaracter = currentCaracter ;
    }

    public char getCurrentCaracter() {
        return currentCaracter;
    }

    private char currentCaracter ;
}
```

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names are written in camelCase.

Comment: Yes for sure, thunks for the notice, am going to correct it

Comment: That fixed the problem. I thought I had to add the keyListener to the content pane but turns out it's possible to just add it to the frame. Thanks a lot!